# Reactjs: Jsx ternary inline of a component (nested ternaries)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, checkbox, jsx

I have a react-bootstrap `<Checkbox >`.

It looks like this:

```
<Checkbox inline onClick={this.handleInclude}> Include </Checkbox>
```

On some occasions I want the Checkbox to be checked. The api suggests doing the following if you want it checked:

`<Checkbox checked inline onClick={this.handleInclude}> Include </Checkbox>`

So now I only want to use the `checked` keyword during certain states.. so I tried using a ternary statement:

```
<Checkbox 
  {this.state.chkbox === true ? "checked" : "" } 
  inline 
  onClick={this.handleInclude}> 
     Include
 </Checkbox>
```

But this throws an `Unexpected token` error. How are you supposed to do this with react?

**EDIT:**

I neglected to mention that the checkbox is indeed wrapped in a ternary

```
{this.state.currentView == "timeline" ?
         <Checkbox 
      {this.state.chkbox === true ? "checked" : "" } 
      inline 
      onClick={this.handleInclude}> 
         Include
     </Checkbox>
: "" 
}
```

I am getting a JSX token error while using the inner `{ }` tags in the ternary operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React handles boolean [form inputs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) using the `checked` property.

```
<input type={"checkbox"} checked={true} />
<input type={"checkbox"} checked={false} />
```

The component should listen for `onChange` events, especially when it's a controlled form input.

```
<input type={"checkbox"} checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.onChange} />
```

Also, heads up:

> Be aware that, in an attempt to normalize change handling for checkbox and radio inputs, React uses a `click` event in place of a `change` event. For the most part this behaves as expected, except when calling `preventDefault` in a `change` handler. `preventDefault` stops the browser from visually updating the input, even if `checked` gets toggled. This can be worked around either by removing the call to `preventDefault`, or putting the toggle of checked in a `setTimeout`.

To summarize, do not call `event.preventDefault()` in your `this.onChange(event)` component method.

---

**Edit**

In JSX, the following syntax means the same thing.

```
<input checked />
<input checked={true} />
```

Please see the [boolean attributes section](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#boolean-attributes) in the docs.

Comment: @ApathyBear please try my suggested solution, it's why I took the time to help you. Instead of using a ternary for the `checked` property, use a boolean property.